# WPF RibbonWindow class GetWindow method

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, windows-ribbon-framework

Normally we use the Window.GetWindow(this).Owner to get the parent of the child window.
But how do we do this with a RibbonWindow. Will typecasting work in this case ?